# How to export html table into pdf or excel in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, export-to-excel, export-to-pdf, html-to-pdf

I have tried many methods but either they have limitation of Number of columns in pdf or they have height limitation.
And for excel, when I open in MAC, it shows HTML.
Can anyone suggest any way from which I can export pdf with More than 4 columns and does not have limitation on number of rows.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use jsPDF library to do this

HTML

```
  <table id="table">
     <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Column 1</th>
       <th>Column 2</th>
       <th>Column 3</th>
       <th>Column 4</th>
       <th>Column 5</th>
       <th>Column 6</th>
     </tr>

     </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
         ... 
      </tr>

    </tbody>

  </table>

  <export-to-pdf elem-id="table"></export-to-pdf>
```

JS

```
  app.directive('exportToPdf', function(){

   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       scope: {
            elemId: '@'
       },
       template: '<button data-ng-click="exportToPdf()">Export to PDF</button>',
       link: function(scope, elem, attr){

          scope.exportToPdf = function() {

              var doc = new jsPDF();

              console.log('elemId 12312321', scope.elemId);

              doc.fromHTML(
              document.getElementById(scope.elemId).innerHTML, 15, 15, {
                     'width': 170
              });

              doc.save('a4.pdf')

           }
       }                   
   }

});
```

In my JSFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Legendary/0h5sro4e/) I didnt reach limit for columns, but I did not find solution about adding css, so you have to do inline styling for html code